# WPF - help converting XAML binding expression to codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Can anyone tell me what is the c# equivalent of the following snippet of XAML ??

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=DataColumns[21].IsVisible, Source={StaticResource viewmodel}, Converter={StaticResource vc}}"                    
                Binding="{Binding SdDevDuration}"
                />
```

Its the visibility binding I cannot get right.  DataGridTextColumn is not a FrameworkElement so no SetBinding method.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I worked this out.  For anyone who's interested you can use the `BindingOperation.SetBinding method.`

The full code is,

```
var newCol = new DataGridTextColumn();
newCol.Binding = new Binding("SdDevDuration");

var visiblityBinding = new Binding("IsVisible");
visiblityBinding.Source = col;
visiblityBinding.Converter = new VisibilityConverter();                        
BindingOperations.SetBinding(newCol, DataGridTextColumn.VisibilityProperty, visiblityBinding);
```

Comment: I will.  SO telling me I have to wait before accepting my own answer.